# How to make sure all the labels print - no matter what

Tags: axis-labels, amcharts4

My graph does not have a lot of space and not all the labels get printed. How to avoid amCharts V4 to add display = none to my labels?

[See the Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aKcvr.png)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I did it!

categoryAxis.renderer.minGridDistance = 10;

I was trying to set that propertie in the grid or for the label, but it is in the axis itself.